# Refactor Similar Methods Redirects Different Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

I wanted to get some advice on how I can refactor some code to make it more DRY, as Rails is very much about DRY. In my controller I have some methods like this:

```
def filter
  if params[:status] == "All" && params[:department] == "All"
    redirect_to admin_organizations_path
  elsif params[:status] != "All" && params[:department] == "All"
    redirect_to admin_organizations_path(status: params[:status])
  elsif params[:status] == "All" && params[:department] != "All"
    redirect_to admin_organizations_path(department: params[:department])
  else
    redirect_to admin_organizations_path(status: params[:status], department: params[:department])
  end
end

def filter_manage
  if params[:status] == "All" && params[:department] == "All"
    redirect_to manage_organizations_path
  elsif params[:status] != "All" && params[:department] == "All"
    redirect_to manage_organizations_path(status: params[:status])
  elsif params[:status] == "All" && params[:department] != "All"
    redirect_to manage_organizations_path(department: params[:department])
  else
    redirect_to manage_organizations_path(status: params[:status], department: params[:department])
  end
end

def filter_index
  if params[:department] == "All"
    redirect_to organizations_path
  else
    redirect_to organizations_path(department: params[:department])
  end
end

def filter_user
  if params[:department] == "All"
    redirect_to user_organizations_path
  else
    redirect_to user_organizations_path(department: params[:department])
  end
end
```

As you can see, the only real difference is where they are redirecting back to, how can make this a into a reusable piece of code that intelligently knows where to redirect back to given the view its coming from, because these methods are just redirecting back to the view they came from.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this much simpler by simply iterating over the params hash and keeping only those params that match a test:

```
def filter_params(*keys)
  params.slice(keys).keep_if do |key, value|
    value.present? && value != "All"
  end
end

def filter
  redirect_to admin_organizations_path(filter_params(:status, :department))
end

def filter_manage
  redirect_to admin_organizations_path(filter_params(:status, :department))
end

def filter_index
  redirect_to organizations_path(filter_params(:department))
end

def filter_user
  redirect_to user_organizations_path(filter_params(:department))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
def filter(flag)
    if params[:status] == "All" && params[:department] == "All"
        myparams = {}
    elsif params[:status] != "All" && params[:department] == "All"
        myparams = {status: params[:status]}
    elsif params[:status] == "All" && params[:department] != "All"
        myparams = {department: params[:department]}
    else
        myparams = {status: params[:status], department: params[:department]}
    end
    ## flag = 0 -> manage_organizations_path
    ## flag = 1 -> admin_organizations_path
    if flag
        admin_organizations_path(myparams)
    else
        manage_organizations_path(myparams)
    end
end
```